# Capitalize book titles without .titleize

Tags: ruby

I need to capitalize each word within a book title for my code. I am having trouble iterating through each element of the array, and capitalizing the first letter. I really can't see what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Title 
  attr_accessor :string 

  def initialize(string) 
    @string = string
  end 

  def fix
    @string.downcase! 
    new_array = []
    if @string.include?(" ")
      new_array << @string.split(" ")
      new_array.map {|word| word.capitalize} 
      new_array.join(" ")
    else 
      @string.capitalize!
    end
  end 
end
```

Specs:

```
describe "Title" do
  describe "fix" do
    it "capitalizes the first letter of each word" do
      expect( Title.new("the great gatsby").fix ).to eq("The Great Gatsby")
    end
    it "works for words with mixed cases" do
      expect( Title.new("liTTle reD Riding hOOD").fix ).to eq("Little Red Riding Hood")
    end
    it "downcases articles" do
      expect( Title.new("The lord of the rings").fix ).to eq("The Lord of the Rings")
      expect( Title.new("The sword And The stone").fix ).to eq("The Sword and the Stone")
      expect( Title.new("the portrait of a lady").fix ).to eq("The Portrait of a Lady")
    end
    it "works for strings with all uppercase characters" do
      expect( Title.new("THE SWORD AND THE STONE").fix ).to eq("The Sword and the Stone")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Explain the actual error or problem you are having.

Comment: One issue that you have is that in this line: `new_array << @string.split(" ")`, you are splitting the string and then pushing that entire array into `new_array`.  So `new_array` is a one-element array containing an array.  That's why you're probably getting an error trying to use `.capitalize` on an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of

```
 new_array = []
```

You don't need to initialize an array for `split`. You are creating an array within an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your fix function should be:

```
def fix
    new_array = @string.split(" ")
    new_array.map {|word| word.capitalize}.join(" ")
end
```

There is no need to downcase in the beginning because capitalize downcases the string and then capitalizes the first letter.

Also this code doesn't care if the string only has one word or more so the if is unnecessary.

And last you were initializing an array and then inserting another array inside using <<, you should just assign what you receive from the split, because it already is a array.